# Stop SQL Server service on application install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

SQL Server service is already installed and service is running.I have created an installer using wix. I need to stop that SQL Server service during the installation of my application.

I have tried the below one

```
</Feature>
   <ComponentRef Id="STOPMSSQLSERVICE" />
</Feature>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR" >
   <Component Id="STOPMSSQLSERVICE" Guid="89CF8BE9-05EE-4C7E-9EFC-0249DD260EBB">
   <ServiceControl Id="StopService"  Stop="install"  Name="SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"  Wait="yes" />
   </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

My application is build without any error,but the service is not stopped after the application installation. I need to stop the SQL Server service which is already running in my machine during the installation of my MSI.

Can any one please tell me what I tried is correct or do I need to add `ServiceControl` to some where else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify service's name e.g. `MSSQLSERVER`, **not** its *display* name `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`.

Here is a [List of SQL Server Service Names](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx).